# При выводе сообщения в Телеграм, вижу Unicode, а не русские слова

Tags: python, telegram, unicode, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть функция, которая парсит сайт и находит в нём слова по маске на русском языке:

```
def get_word_by_mask(mask):
    if len(mask.strip()) == 0:
        logger.error('Пользователь не ввел слово')
        return 'Введите шаблон для поиска'
    else:
        page = get_html(config.URL_FOR_WORD + mask + '&def=')
        word = []
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
        data = soup.find_all('div', class_='wd')
        for item in data:
            w = item.find('a')
            word.append(w.text.strip())
        print(word)
        return word
```

При выводе результата функции в консоль, я вижу их на русском языке, а при выводе в Телеграм - в юникоде:

[image: Вывод в Телеграм]

Помогите побороть проблему пожалуйста.

Comment: Я не работал с библиотеками телеграма, но предположу, что при отправке не-строки кто-то автоматически конвертирует не-строку в строку при помощи JSON. Переделайте `word` в строку как вам надо и возвращайте строку, и, возможно, всё станет хорошо

Comment: Попробуйте `return ', '.join(word)`

Comment: Спасибо, товарищи! Это решило проблему!